# IE10 TagIt input box launches file upload dialog

Tags: jquery, html, dialog, tag-it

There is a bug when using the TagIt JQuery library on IE10 browsers.  The widget presents an input box to the user, into which he can enter email multiple email addresses.  This information can then be passed back to the server.  Here is a screen capture of what TagIt looks like in the UI:

[image]

and here is the HTML code which, along with the JQuery TagIt library, generated the above:

```
<input type="hidden" id="some_id">
<ul id="mailShareTags" tag-it />
```

**The problem:**

If we type an email address into TagIt and press <kbd>ENTER</kbd> once, then the name gets entered as shown above.  However, if we focus the TagIt input, and press <kbd>ENTER</kbd> a *second* time, without entering another name, then it opens a file upload dialog box.  While this isn't a blocker, it is certainly isn't the behavior we want.  This occurs only on IE10 and not on any other of our supported browsers.

Is there some way, programatically or via HTML, that we can prevent the file dialog from opening on IE10?